# different application signatures BUT same keystore

Tags: android, installation, uninstallation, keystore, signatures

when I updated my android app i got the following error message:

- Re-installation failed due to different application signatures.
- You must perform a full uninstall of the application. WARNING: This will remove the application data!
- Please execute 'adb ******' in a shell.
- Launch canceled!

I personally got no problems with that but my question now is ... if I export the apk with the same keystore I used for previous updates. Is the app update a simple download for my users ?
Or will they have any problems with it ?

Btw: I didnt format my computer or changed anything about my eclipse folder or my folder where I save my keystore etc.

Thanks in advance!

Greets

Comment: but why is my "signature" different now ?

Comment: I have no idea. There are tutorials on how to properly update an app though. Those might give you hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the app update a simple download for my users ?

Only if it was signed by the same production signing key as you used originally, which would not appear to be the case here.

> I didnt format my computer or changed anything about my eclipse folder or my folder where I save my keystore etc.

Despite that, you attempted to update an APK with one signed by a different signing key (e.g., debug vs. production). Use **`jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs ...`**, where `...` is the path to your APK, to dump signing information, so you can compare your old APK to your new one.

Comment: so the error message could have occured because I started a debug run on eclipse ? 
And what can I appart from that option ... because i don't have an old APK and didn't find the option to download my actual APK from the store.

Comment: @user2277241: If your device or emulator has the production APK installed, signed with your production signing key, then yes, trying to install a debug APK signed the debug keystore will give this error.

Comment: @user2277241: "i don't have an old APK" -- **NEVER EVER EVER EVER EVER SHIP PRODUCTION SOFTWARE WITHOUT MAINTAINING A COPY OF WHAT YOU SHIPPED**. That is all.

Comment: alright i think i'll never do that again :(
so am i right? if the play store doesn't show any errors when i upload a new apk to production that means there will be no problems for my users ? because i tried to upload it (no i didn't press the final "OK" button) ... but until then there was no error message shown by the store

Comment: @user2277241: "if the play store doesn't show any errors when i upload a new apk to production that means there will be no problems for my users ?" -- I'm pretty sure the Play Store will yell at you if there is a mismatched pair of signing keys, so you should be OK.

Comment: thanks so much @CommonsWare! i really hope i was lucky this time and i'll never ship software without saving a backup :/